# Transforming collection using lodash

Tags: javascript, json, collections, lodash

I have a query which give me Json data; for example I have the following Json

```
{
"salesInvoices":

    [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "salesInvoiceLines":
        [
            {
                "ItemCode": "Apple",
                "UnitCode": "piece",
                "Quantity": "10"
            },
            {
                "ItemCode": "Orange",
                "UnitCode": "box",
                "Quantity": "2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "salesInvoiceLines":
        [
            {
                "ItemCode": "Apple",
                "UnitCode": "piece",
                "Quantity": "20"
            },
            {
                "ItemCode": "Orange",
                "UnitCode": "piece",
                "Quantity": "21"
            },
            {
                "ItemCode": "Orange",
                "UnitCode": "box",
                "Quantity": "1"
            }
        ]
    }
    ]

}
```

I want to group data by item-unit pairs into following format:

```
[
  { item : 'Apple', unit : 'piece', totalQuantity : 30 },
  { item : 'Orange', unit : 'piece', totalQuantity : 21 },
  { item : 'Orange', unit : 'box', totalQuantity : 3 }
]
```

I tired the following code using lodash library but it doesn't work

```
   var sumQuantity = function(total, item){
        return total + item.Quantity
    }

    var transformList = function(line){
        return _.map(line.SalesInvoiceLines, function(invoice){
            return _.map(invoice, function(line){
                return {
                    item: line.ItemCode,
                    unit: line.UnitCode,
                    totalQuantity: _.reduce(line.Quantity, sumQuantity, 0)
                }
            })
        });
    };

    var groupedList = _.groupBy(data.d.results, function(line) {
        return line.ItemCode + line.UnitCode;
    });

    var list = _.chain(groupedList)
    .map(transformList)
    .flatten()
    .value();
```

How can I get the mentioned result?

Comment: You already have an error in your origin JSON: the property `salesInvoiceLines` is doubled and the second occurence will overwrite the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Input
var data = {
    "salesInvoices": [{
        "id": "1",
        "salesInvoiceLines": [{
            "ItemCode": "Apple",
            "UnitCode": "piece",
            "Quantity": "10"
        }, {
            "ItemCode": "Orange",
            "UnitCode": "box",
            "Quantity": "2"
        }]
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "salesInvoiceLines": [{
            "ItemCode": "Apple",
            "UnitCode": "piece",
            "Quantity": "20"
        }, {
            "ItemCode": "Orange",
            "UnitCode": "piece",
            "Quantity": "21"
        }, {
            "ItemCode": "Orange",
            "UnitCode": "box",
            "Quantity": "1"
        }]
    }]

}
```

```
//Output
/*
[
  { item : 'Apple', unit : 'piece', totalQuantity : 30 },
  { item : 'Orange', unit : 'piece', totalQuantity : 21 },
  { item : 'Orange', unit : 'box', totalQuantity : 3 }
]
*/
```

```
// Code
_.chain(_.flatten(_.map(data.salesInvoices, 'salesInvoiceLines')))
    .reduce(function(output, curr) {
        output[curr.ItemCode + '_' + curr.UnitCode] = output[curr.ItemCode + '_' + curr.UnitCode] ? output[curr.ItemCode + '_' + curr.UnitCode] + parseInt(curr.Quantity) : parseInt(curr.Quantity);
        return output;
    }, {})
    .reduce(function(result, value, key) {
        result.push({
            item: key.split('_')[0],
            unit: key.split('_')[1],
            totalQuantity: value
        });
        return result;
    }, []).value();
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry I can't give you a concrete working example. From what I've seen you have the following conceptional errors in your code:

1. I guess the initial groupBy statement is wrong. Assuming that data.d.results is the same as the sample JSON you've posted, then you can't access `line.ItemCode + line.UnitCode;` there. Instead, you'll just get one iteration for `salesInvoices`.
2. You have one level of `_.map` calls which you don't need:

   `return _.map(line.SalesInvoiceLines, function(invoice){
           return _.map(invoice, function(line){`

=> An invoice already is an invoice. It does not make sense to iterate over the properties of the invoice (neither does it make sense to call them `line`).

3. It does not make sense to use the _.reduce() as you do in `totalQuantity: _.reduce(line.Quantity, sumQuantity, 0)` because `line.Quantity` already is a primitive number. You can't "reduce" that.

My suggestions are:

1. get the basic transformation right and try to extract all invoices into a flat array
2. then you can _.reduce() this array to an intermediate object, with keys holding "line.ItemCode + line.UnitCode", pointing to objects of the form you desire to have in the end, e.g. `{ item : 'Apple', unit : 'piece', totalQuantity : 30 }`. On every reduce-iteration, you just determine this "unique key", test if the object already exists, if not you create it with totalQuantity = 1, otherwise you just increment the totalQuantity.
3. finnaly, call _.values() on the intermediate result from step 2.

Comment: Thanks @Nic! I tried to implement what you said. I will post it as answer.

Comment: Mark answer as correct. It helps people to know it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it using the following code:

```
    var invoicelines = [];
    var lines = _.map(data, 'SalesInvoiceLines');

    var getLines = lines.forEach(function (entry){
        var l = entry.results;
        l.forEach(function (line){
            invoicelines.push(line);
        })
    });

    var list = _.chain(invoicelines)
       .groupBy(function(sll) {
            return sll.ItemCode + sll.UnitCode;
        })
        .map(function(value, key) {
            return [key, _.reduce(value, function(result, currentObject) {
                return {
                    Item: currentObject.ItemCode,
                    Unit: currentObject.UnitCode,
                    Quantity: result.Quantity + currentObject.Quantity
                }
            }, {
                Quantity: 0
            })];
        })
        .object()
        .sortBy(function(item) {
           return item.Quantity
        })
        .value();
```